# Is there a way to set ddns local to not forward to admin interface

Tags: firewall, pfsense, ddns

I am running pfsense and would like to configure my site to work locally. I have a ddns setup working externally with no-ip. The problem is I'm trying to get my local setup to work.

Locally I enter domain name, ie example.com, and get redirected to the pfsense admin interface. I have disabled dns administration so even if they log in with correct user/pass they can't administer it, but what is the easiest way to allow example.com to work correctly from local network. Can I force traffic out and then back to dmz? I'm running multiple name based virtual hosts. The only other option I can think of is to config some vhosts on different ports and deny from all except my lan subnet? Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

multiple options
http://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Why_can%27t_I_access_forwarded_ports_on_my_WAN_IP_from_my_LAN/OPTx_networks%3F